# Xtext - AutoEdits with backspace

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, xtext

Assume following situation:
We have a document, which contains spaces
( *for example denoted as _* )
And we have caret behind those (4)spaces

```
_ _ _ _|
```

I want editor to delete all 4 spaces instead of one when user presses backspace.

I am extending *DefaultIndentLineAutoEditStrategy* where I override following method

`public void customizeDocumentCommand(IDocument d, DocumentCommand c)`

I am facing two problems:

1. How to detect backspace have been used from DocumentCommand? If you use newline `c.text` contains `"\n"` or `"\r\n"` but if you use backspace it equals to `""`.
2. How do I insert 3 more backspaces? Appending `"\b"` to `c.text` does not work.

Comment: does setting command.offset and command.length not help?

Comment: Ok I detect backspace like this
if (c.text.equals("") && c.length == 1) and c.offset-=3; c.length=4; just did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to implement it.

1. `if (c.text.equals("") && c.length == 1)` condition detects usage of backspace/delete
2. Deleting 3 more characters can be done as following:
   `c.offset-=3;
   c.length=4;`

whole implementation can look like this:

```
private void handleBackspace(IDocument d, DocumentCommand c) {
        if (c.offset == -1 || d.getLength() == 0)
            return;
        int p = (c.offset == d.getLength() ? c.offset - 1 : c.offset);
        IRegion info;
        try {
            info = d.getLineInformationOfOffset(p);
            String line = d.get(info.getOffset(), info.getLength());
            int lineoffset = info.getOffset();
            /*Make sure unindent is made only if user is indented and has caret in correct position */
            if ((p-lineoffset+1)%4==0&&((line.startsWith("    ") && !line.startsWith("     ")) || (line.startsWith("        ") && !line.startsWith("         ")))){ //1 or 2 level fixed indent
                c.offset-=3;
                c.length=4;
            }

        }catch (org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```